# Exercise for playing wordgames with user input

Tags: java

I'm trying to getting integer keyboard input to call the corresponding method.

invalid input works, keyboard input 3 works, input 2 exits, input 1 calls the wrong method.
I've not yet worked on the subtring and points problem method yet.

Regards, and I appreciate your feedback.

```
import java.io.File;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.InputMismatchException;



public class WordGames {

public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {


    getSelection();
    File file = new File("DICTIONARY.txt");
        if (file.isFile() == true) {
        }
        else {
            System.out.println("File doesn't exist.  Exiting.");
            System.exit(0);  
        }
    
    subStringProblem();
    pointsProblem();
            
    }
    
    static String getSelection() {
        Scanner keyboardInput = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Welcome to the Word Games program menu.");
        System.out.println("Select from one of the following options.");
        System.out.println("1. Substring problem.");
        System.out.println("2. Points problem.");
        System.out.println("3. Exit.");
        System.out.println("Enter your selections: ");
        
        
        if ( ! keyboardInput.hasNextInt()) {
           
           System.out.println("Invalid option.  Try again.");
           getSelection();
            
        } else if (keyboardInput.hasNextInt(1)){
            subStringProblem(); 
            getSelection();
            
        } else if (keyboardInput.hasNextInt(2)){
            pointsProblem();
            getSelection();
            
        } else if (keyboardInput.hasNextInt(3)){
        }    System.out.println("Good Bye!");
             System.exit(0);  
        return null;
    }
        
        
    static String subStringProblem() {
        System.out.println("Substring problem.");
        System.out.println("Enter a Substring:");
    return null;
    }
    static String pointsProblem() {
        System.out.println("Points problem.");
        
    return null;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**1. Proper indentation**

Please have a look at a [style guide](https://google.github.io/styleguide/javaguide.html). One important topic of style guides is how to "correctly" indent your code:

```java
import java.io.File;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.InputMismatchException;

public class WordGames {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
        getSelection();
        File file = new File("DICTIONARY.txt");
        if (file.isFile() == true) {
        }
        else {
            System.out.println("File doesn't exist.  Exiting.");
            System.exit(0);  
        }

        subStringProblem();
        pointsProblem();
    }
    
    static String getSelection() {
        Scanner keyboardInput = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Welcome to the Word Games program menu.");
        System.out.println("Select from one of the following options.");
        System.out.println("1. Substring problem.");
        System.out.println("2. Points problem.");
        System.out.println("3. Exit.");
        System.out.println("Enter your selections: ");
              
        if (!keyboardInput.hasNextInt()) {
           
           System.out.println("Invalid option.  Try again.");
           getSelection();
            
        } else if (keyboardInput.hasNextInt(1)) {
            subStringProblem(); 
            getSelection();
            
        } else if (keyboardInput.hasNextInt(2)) {
            pointsProblem();
            getSelection();
            
        } else if (keyboardInput.hasNextInt(3)) {
            System.out.println("Good Bye!");
            System.exit(0);
        }  
        return null;
    }
            
    static String subStringProblem() {
        System.out.println("Substring problem.");
        System.out.println("Enter a Substring:");
        return null;
    }
    
    static String pointsProblem() {
        System.out.println("Points problem.");     
        return null;
    }
}
```

**2. Empty if**

```java
if (file.isFile() == true) {
}
else {
    System.out.println("File doesn't exist.  Exiting.");
    System.exit(0);  
}
```

This is not necessary. Just use

```java
if (file.isFile()) {
}
else {
    System.out.println("File doesn't exist.  Exiting.");
    System.exit(0);  
}
```

Without an `==` the `if` will automatically check if the value is true.
Even better:

```java
if(!file.isFile()) {
    System.out.println("File doesn't exist.  Exiting.");
    System.exit(0);  
}
```

Empty `if`-statements should be avoided.

**3.Input validation**

In `getSelection()`, your program doesn't crash when the user enters a letter instead of a number. That is good. But your program does crash, when the user enters a number not equal to 1, 2 or 3. This problem can be avoided like this:

```java
int sel = 0;
try{
    sel = keyboardInput.nextInt();
} catch (InputMismatchException e){
    keyboardInput.next();
    System.out.println("Invalid option. Try again.");
    getSelection();
}

if (sel == 1) {
    subStringProblem(); 
    getSelection();
}
else if (sel == 2) {
    pointsProblem();
    getSelection();
}   
else if (sel == 3) {
    System.out.println("Good Bye!");
    System.exit(0);
}
else {
    System.out.println("Invalid option. Try again.");
    getSelection();
}
```

If you are not familiar with `try-catch` yet, I suggest reading the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/catch.html).

**4.Unnecessary returns**

If you don't want to return something in your methods, you can use `void` as return type instead of `String`.
For example:

```java
static String subStringProblem() {
    System.out.println("Substring problem.");
    System.out.println("Enter a Substring:");
    return null;
}
```

should be replaced with

```java
static void subStringProblem() {
    System.out.println("Substring problem.");
    System.out.println("Enter a Substring:");
}
```

**5. Access modifiers**

It is considered good practice to always add Access modifiers to your methods. Instead of

```java
static void getSelection() {
```

it should be

```java
private static void getSelection() {
```

**6. throws**

The `throws`-keyword in the main-method is not necessary.

**Code**

```java
import java.io.File;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.util.InputMismatchException;

public class WordGames {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        getSelection();
        File file = new File("DICTIONARY.txt");
        if(!file.isFile()) {
            System.out.println("File doesn't exist. Exiting.");
            System.exit(0);  
        }
        subStringProblem();
        pointsProblem();
    }
    
    private static void getSelection() {
        Scanner keyboardInput = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Welcome to the Word Games program menu.");
        System.out.println("Select from one of the following options.");
        System.out.println("1. Substring problem.");
        System.out.println("2. Points problem.");
        System.out.println("3. Exit.");
        System.out.println("Enter your selections: ");
         
        int sel = 0;
        try{
            sel = keyboardInput.nextInt();
        } catch (InputMismatchException e){
            keyboardInput.next();
            System.out.println("Invalid option. Try again.");
            getSelection();
        }
        
        if (sel == 1) {
            subStringProblem(); 
            getSelection();
        }
        else if (sel == 2) {
            pointsProblem();
            getSelection();
        }   
        else if (sel == 3) {
            System.out.println("Good Bye!");
            System.exit(0);
        }
        else {
            System.out.println("Invalid option. Try again.");
            getSelection();
        }
    }
            
    private static void subStringProblem() {
        System.out.println("Substring problem.");
        System.out.println("Enter a Substring:");
    }

    private static void pointsProblem() {
        System.out.println("Points problem.");     
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

`getSelection` is a recursive method that also terminate the program. There is no need to return anything.
All the code behind that call in your main method will never be executed and is useless.

Answer (score 1):

> ```
>         Scanner keyboardInput = new Scanner(System.in);
> ```

You call this on each recursive call to `getSelection`.  That's unnecessary.  You could simply create one `Scanner` and use it for the entire program.  That could be as simple as adding a class variable:

```
    private static Scanner keyboardInput = new Scanner(System.in);
```

Or you could use a [`try`-with-resources](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html) and pass it into a constructor for your `WordGames` object.

```
        try (Scanner keyboardInput = new Scanner(System.in)) {
            WordGames game = new WordGames(keyboardInput);
            game.play();
        }
```

Now the `Scanner` will be automatically closed when finished.

The static version will automatically close the `Scanner` when the program finishes.  Not quite as clean as using the `try`-with-resources but acceptable for a `Scanner`.

Your original code will keep opening new `Scanner` instances for each invalid entry and never closes any of them.  With enough entries, it would be possible to crash the program that way.

Of course, even without multiple copies, the recursive calls themselves use an ever increasing number of call stacks.  So you can still crash the program just from the recursion.  But that will take longer if you only have a single `Scanner`.  Regardless, it would be better to rewrite your program's logic as a loop (`while`, `for`, etc.) rather than recursively.  Recursion is used when you care about the state.  But in this case, you don't.

As a practical matter, it would be difficult to crash this simple program by entering an endless stream of 4s.  But it wouldn't be impossible.  And it's probably a bad pattern to get in the habit of using, because if the program is less I/O based, the computer can more easily overrun its limits.